I'm using Asp.net core 8 and I want to seperate projects in a solution without using WebApi, MicroServices or Classlibrary, How can I do this?
I create an Asp.net core MVC WebApllication project that has a MVC Login Service, and now I want to add another project (SignalR chat project) in the same solution, but when a project is Running, second project will be off.
How this possible to use multiple MVC project in a solution that working together?
I could'nt redirect client into the second project.

Do you mean you want to run two project at same time? If this is your requirement, you could right click the solution and select configure startup projects.  Then you could select multiple startup projects.  https://i.sstatic.net/pJhhL.png

yes, Ido. I wanted to run two project at the same time, Thank you.

Then, what should I do to link projects?

What you mean about link projects.  They have different port, you just need to use the lunchsetting.json's url and write the codes inside the each projects.

I mean how to connect and relate projects together, for example, I want to use webapplication externel login controller in chat project, I don't have any idea what to do.  @BrandoZhang

It's different things, for example, if you want to use MVC application login controller, you need to keep the two application contain same security settings(if you are using identity). Normally, for this kind of scenario , we will put the two projects inside the same project. It will save a lot of codes, if you still want to use two projects, you need share the cookie between these two projects, or modify the your MVC projects to generate the token and let the chat projects check that token and use it.  This is a complex question and if you want, you could create a new thread to talk it.

Thank you for your accurate answer. I appreciate it. @BrandoZhang

I don't know how to mark a comment as an answer. @BrandoZhang

If you want to run the two projects at same time, you could right click the solution and select configure startup projects.




how to connect and relate projects together, for example, I want to use webapplication externel login controller in chat project, I don't have any idea what to do.

It's different things, for example, if you want to use MVC application login controller, you need to keep the two application contain same security settings(if you are using identity). Normally, for this kind of scenario , we will put the two projects inside the same project. It will save a lot of codes, if you still want to use two projects, you need share the cookie between these two projects, or modify the your MVC projects to generate the token and let the chat projects check that token and use it.
